# urllib.urlretrieve() downloads invalid images when filename has two periods in it

Tags: python, image, download

This is silly. Every time I try to download a group of images that have periods in the file name the images show as "invalid" after being downloaded and don't open properly on my machine. Never encountered this problem before. What gives? How do I work around this?

```
image_url = "http://somewebsite.com/images/icon.50.png"
urllib.urlretrieve(image_url, "icon.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with urllib? The image you posted seems like an actual image, just not the image you expected?

Comment: I suspect that the server operators have implemented checks to make it difficult for others to hotlink their images.

Comment: I can confirm it works just fine locally so it can't be an issue with urllib.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is but using requests instead of urllib.urlretrieve worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py

Comment: I would still like to know why it didn't work with urllib.urlretrieve?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file is large enough...

Try this

```
def download_file(url):
local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
# NOTE the stream=True parameter
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
        if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
return local_filename
```